# SQL Server stored procedure with condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I'm trying to create a conditional event when I press an `<asp:button>` in C#.

I have a `GridView` related to two database tables (in SQL Server). I should insert different values in one of them, every day.

Inside the `GridView`:

- I have a `BoundField` with the `ID` for each item inside the database table
- I have two `TemplateFields` with a textbox, named `StartGV` and `EndGV`

Outside the `GridView`:

- I have an `<asp:TextBox>` with an `AjaxCalendarExtender`. There I should select the date. The textbox is `TextDate`

So, when I press the `<asp:button>`, the event should:

- check for each row in the `Gridview` (with the `ID` from the `GridView`'s first column and the date selected in the textbox outside the `GridView`) if the record already exists in the database

  - If yes, the database record should be updated with the new values
  - If no, the a new record should be inserted with the values

I'm using stored procedures for update and insert.

This is the code in C#:

```
protected void BotonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            //HERE I SAVE THE TEXTBOXS FROM GRIDVIEW INSIDE A VARIABLE
            TextBox StartGV = row.FindControl("StartGV") as TextBox;
            TextBox EndGV = row.FindControl("EndGV") as TextBox;
            DateTime Date = DateTime.ParseExact(TextDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            //HERE I EXTRACT THE VALUE FROM THE FIRST COLUMN (THE ID)
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                string ID = row.Cells[0].Text;

            //HERE I CHECK IF THE ROW ALREADY EXISTS IN DATABASE TABLE:

                //IF YES, UPDATE:
                if (CADCATOPS.CADBatchHandoff.CheckTableDB(Convert.ToInt32(ID), Convert.ToString(Date)))
                {
                    string connectionString = @"MY CONNECTION STRING";
                    SqlConnection Connection1 = null;
                    SqlTransaction Transaction1 = null;
                    {
                        Connection1 = new SqlConnection();
                        Connection1.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                        Connection1.Open();
                        Transaction1 = Connection1.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable);
                        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE", Connection1, Transaction1);
                        command1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        command1.Parameters.Clear();
                        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", Convert.ToDateTime(StartGV.Text));
                        if (EndGV.Text != "")
                        {
                            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End", Convert.ToDateTime(EndGV.Text));
                        }
                        command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Transaction1.Commit();
                        Connection1.Close();
                    }
                }

                //IF NO, INSERT:
                if (!CADCATOPS.CADBatchHandoff.CheckTableDB(Convert.ToInt32(IDBatch), Convert.ToString(FechaCT1)))
                {
                    //FIRST OF ALL, CHECK IF THE "STARTGV" TEXTBOX IS NOT EMPTY. IF IT'S EMPTY, THE PROCESS WILL NOT START FOR THIS ROW.
                    if (StartGV.Text != "")
                    {
                        string connectionString = @"MY CONNECTION STRING";
                        SqlConnection Connection1 = null;
                        SqlTransaction Transaction1 = null;
                        {
                        Connection1 = new SqlConnection();
                        Connection1.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                        Connection1.Open();
                        Transaction1 = Connection1.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable);
                        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT", Connection1, Transaction1);
                        command1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        command1.Parameters.Clear();
                        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start", Convert.ToDateTime(StartGV.Text));
                        if (EndGV.Text != "")
                        {
                            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End", Convert.ToDateTime(EndGV.Text));
                        }
                        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(ID));
                        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE", Convert.ToDateTime(DATE.Text));
                        command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Transaction1.Commit();
                        Connection1.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So, this is working but something is wrong:

- The `INSERT` condition works fine.
- The `UPDATE` is not working ok: the "StartGV" and EndGV" values selected for the process is ALWAYS the same as the last row. This is not happening with the INSERT process.

Why could it be?

Edit

I forget to show the `SELECT` statements in my project:

Inside the table adapter, I have created this query, named `CheckTableDB`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM BatchDatos 
WHERE (ID = @ID) and (DATE=@DATE)
```

And then, in c#:

```
public static bool CheckTableDB(int ID, string DATE)
{
    return adapter.CheckTableDB(ID, DATE) != 0;
}
```

I use this for `UPDATE` and `INSERT`. It's working ok for `INSERT`, that means the issue is not here.

Comment: You don't use id in your update. It may result in your problem.

Comment: Yes, Im using it, in the condition "if exists" before start the update process. I used "foreach", that means UPDATE and INSERT are working in the same row. Then I check if the ID and the Date already exists in the DB. If yes, the row will be updated, if not, the row will be inserted.

Comment: And inside the UPDATE I don't need to update the ID (neither the date), that's why Im not using it.

Comment: You don't need to *update* ID but you need to find a row in DB based on ID. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Oh, I forget to show in the first post the SELECT.

Comment: If ID is a primary key of your table then update query (inside SP) probably looks like this: `update myTable set start=@start, [end]=@end where id=@id`. Or you do something else?

Comment: Alex, now my post is updated. You can check at it. The issue is not in the "Select" operation, because it's working ok. I thing the issue is in the structure of the condition.

Comment: the issue is not in your `select`. It is in your `update`. without condition `where` you update all rows in the table.

Comment: And was that! Thank you!. Post it as "answer" so I can vote it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without condition where you update all rows in the table. You need to use ID from your GV to update exact row in the DB.